# Extend a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ to a function on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Which of the following given functions $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ can be extended to become a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$?

1. $\sin{1\over x}$
2. ${1-\cos x}\over x^2$
3. $\cos {1\over x}$
4. $1\over x$

So , continuous  extension would require $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=f(0).$$

Now , among all  of  them  only  option $2$ takes a **limit** while approaching $0$  by  **L'Hospital's Rule.(being  $0\over 0$  form)**  and that limit  is  $1\over 2$.So,defining $f(0)={1\over 2}$, this can be extended  continuously on $[0,\infty)$. The others do not take  limit as $x$ tends to $0.$  so **option $2$** is a correct answer.

That is right,yes $?$ As I'm sure about $1\over x$  and $\sin {1\over x}$ not taking limit at $x\rightarrow 0$ , I'm  not  sure about the function $\cos {1\over x}.$ So , that is why  this question.

Comment: $cos(\frac{1}{x})$ and $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ behave very similarly, and both of them go crazy when $x\to 0$.

Comment: What difference is there (to you) between $\sin 1/x$ at $0$ and $\cos 1/x$ at $0$?

Comment: Your answer is true and the functions in 1, 3 and 4 are discontinuous at zero which is not removable.

Comment: For $\cos {1\over x}$ and  $\sin {1\over x}$, take $t:=1/x$ and see what the limits are when $t→∞$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Actually  not  much  difference  behavior-wise,. Both are bounded and  very near to $0$  their graphs look  pretty  much  the  same . Just  looked  at them . So, all  $3$  dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos\frac{1}{x}
$$
does not exists by contradiction.

Let:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos\frac{1}{x}=l
$$
chose $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$, by the definition of limit we have:

$$
\left|\cos\frac{1}{x}-l \right|< \frac{1}{2}
\quad if \quad 0<x<\delta \quad \text{for some} \quad \delta >0
$$

Now we can allways find an integer $n$ such that
$$
x'=\frac{1}{2n\pi}<\delta \quad \text{and} \quad x''=\frac{1}{2(n+1)\pi}<\delta
$$
and for such $n$ we have:
$$
\cos\frac{1}{x'}=1 \quad \text{and} \quad  \cos\frac{1}{x''}=-1 
$$this implies that:
$$
|-1-l|<\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad |1-l|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
i.e.
$$
|l+1|<\frac{1}{2}\quad \text{and} \quad |l-1|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
and this implies $|1-(-1)|<1$: contadiction!

So the discontinuity at $x=0$ is not removable and you are right also for the question (3).

Comment: I think maybe a better way to say this is that there are two different limits. Boiling it down to the definition of a limit seems to be a bit clunky to me.

Comment: It is not true that there are two different limits. Also the limit form left does not exists ( the proof is substantially the same) and, anyway,  the OP asks for the limit from right.

Comment: There are two distinct subsequential limits as evidenced in your post which is very clearly what I meant in my comment.

Comment: What do you means by '' subsequential limits''?  Sorry, but this is a terminology that maybe can be useful in english, but that I does not know!

Comment: I guess it's probably a very English-specific term, but a subsequential limit is a limit associated to a subsequence of your original sequence. The term is used a bit more loosely than that in everyday use, though.

Comment: OK, if I understand well than there are subsequences that has as limit any $l \in [-1,1]$. And this, in my opinion , means that there is no limit for the function.

Comment: Yep you understand correctly. It's just easiest to construct the subsequences corresponding to limits of $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}}$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathcal{R}$ because it has a limit at $0$, namely $- \frac{1}{2}$.